# How to put my C# Program in a sleep mode?

Tags: c#, sleep

OK , so lets say I have built an Application in C# and when you are working with this application it uses a lot of the computer's Memory and now I want to do something that when its Idle or I'm not working with it , it stops using the memory but I can go back and start working where I left off.
Is there anywhere to Temporarily pause the application so its not using the Ram ?

Comment: The only way would be to serialize and store it the data you need and release the memory you are using. When you are ready to process again, you would just deserialize it into memory and continue.

Comment: The system does this for you.

Comment: @scottm , Ok so how do I do that ?

Comment: @FinalContest this question was asked 3 years ago..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the user minimizes your application, Windows will (eventually) swap its address space to disk, freeing up RAM for other programs.

You don't need to do anything.

Comment: I used Task Manager to see if it does that , unfortunately it doesnt free up the RAM enough.

Comment: Yes it does. You memory is being moved to the disk (virtual memory). If after a while the user starts using your application again, your app will be slow a little bit until most of the page faults are over.

Comment: Yes it does. Windows virtual memory is hard to understand. Task Manager is not a memory profiling tool.

Comment: So is there anyway to make my application use less of the RAM ?
Im looking for a General Answer , like using a piece of code that helps , for example I use Application.DoEvents(); to prevent my application from crashing ... you know what im saying ?

Comment: Well, free up your memory. delete unused object.

Comment: @user: Using `Application.DoEvents()` **will not** prevent your application from crashing; it will make your code more likely to crash due to re-entrancy.  There is no magic incantation that makes code faster or more memory-efficient.  Except under rare and specialized circumstances, you should not be calling `Application.DoEvents()`.  Instead, using threading, tasks, or background workers as appropriate.

Comment: If a program is idle and another program wants RAM, the system will make the idle app page its RAM to swap file and give it to the needy app. Hard to see where DoEvents comes into this.

Comment: No-one said programming would be easy

Comment: So , basically its unnecessary to worry about freeing up the RAM by the own application ? ..

Comment: Correct.  However, you can probably optimize your code to use less memory in general.

Comment: Yeah , I have tried that. 
Thanks Thou :)
Ill accept your answer ;)